# How to override the backButton default method in android?

Tags: java, android

in this case, i have some divs element show in my html page located in asset folder and i load that page using WebView. what I want is when i press the backButton then it hides all divs element. but the problem is when backButton press it close my app. is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

What I observe, you loaded url in **webview** which is an **Activity** and you override the back event of activity now you want to some action on loaded page in **webview**.

*Just try this trick, take one boolean, make it true once page loaded in webview and check the same boolean in backpress event.*

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(boolean){
//do action
}else{
super.onBackPressed();
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

public class AndroidBackButtonActivity extends Activity {

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    //Display alert message when back button has been pressed
    backButtonHandler();
    return;
}

public void backButtonHandler() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            AndroidBackButtonActivity.this);
    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle("Leave application?");
    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage("Are you sure you want to leave the application?");
    // Setting Icon to Dialog
    alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.dialog_icon);
    // Setting Positive "Yes" Button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    finish();
                }
            });
    // Setting Negative "NO" Button
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // Write your code here to invoke NO event
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

}

Comment: your code works perfectly but it's not waht i'm looking for... thanks

Answer (score 0):

problem SOLVED... onBackPressed method i load the javascript using webview

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webView.loadUrl("javascript:$('#settingEdit').hide()");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    // Write your code here

    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272), because they don't teach the solution.

Comment: thanks for answering but it's not exactly what i want ;) it still closes my app.